# How is the potential function "plug" into the relativistic wave equations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, wavefunction, potential-energy, mass-energy

In [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/293063/) question I “derive” the Schrödinger equation. A similar argument could be used for the Klein-Gordon’s or Dirac’s equations (with Dirac's equation having one more step of linearization of the [Klein-Gordon Hamiltonian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation#Dirac's_coup)).

**In short** these derivations are as follows:

1. Admit the plane wave ansatz
   $$ψ=e^{i(kx-ω t)} \tag{1}$$
2. Get its derivatives with respect to $x$ and $t$.

$$\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
k^2=- ψ^{-1} \frac{∂^2ψ}{∂x^2}\\
ω =iψ^{-1} \frac{∂ψ}{∂t}
\end{cases}
\tag{2}
\end{equation}$$

3. Make use of the De Broglie’s relations

$$\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
E=ħω\\
p=ħk
\end{cases}
\tag{3}
\end{equation}$$

4. Use the right dispersion relation

$$\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
E=\frac{p^2}{2m}+U\\
E^2=c^2p^2+m^2c^4
\end{cases}
\tag{4}
\end{equation}$$

Substituting (2) into (4) via (3) we get Schrödinger’s and Klein-Gordon’s equations. The thing is, how do we add $U$ into the relativistic one’s if that relation is supposed to be valid for free particles only? (restrict relativity)

---

**PS: I’m aware that wave equations are not *rigorously speaking*, derived. They are postulated. Take these “derivations” as arguments in favour for the definition of a certain wave equation.

Comment: More on [potential energy in SR](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potential-energy+mass-energy).

Comment: Your equation is wrong, $k^2 = - \partial_{xx} \psi$ should be $k^2 \psi = -\partial_{xx} \psi$, and similarly for the other.

Comment: @JamalS Thanks. It was missing a $ψ^{-1}$. I already made the changes.

Comment: This question solved my problem. Made a rookie's mistake. Thanks all. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/389325/